# Perlin noise different implementations

Tags: math, perlin-noise

I have read some articles on perlin noise but each seems to have their own way of implementation:

1. In [this](https://adrianb.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html) article, the gradient function returns a single double value.
2. In [this](https://rtouti.github.io/graphics/perlin-noise-algorithm) article, the gradient is generated as a 3D vector.
3. In [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/procedural-generation-virtual-worlds/perlin-noise-part-2) article a static 256 array of random gradient vectors is generated and a random one is picked using the permutation table and then more complex details of spherical gradients are discussed.

And these are just a few of the articles I saw. With all these variations of the same algorithm which one do I use or which one is suitable for what purpose?

I have generated terrains and height maps with each of these techniques and their respective outputs widely differ in their own ways and I can't tell if I am doing it right cause I don't know what to look for in the output (cause it's just random values at the end)

I am just looking for some context on when to use what so any insight would be very usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement the same algorithm, some are faster or slower than others, some are easier or harder to understand. [The original implementation by Ken Perlin](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eperlin/noise/) is difficult to understand by just looking at it. So some of the articles you linked (including #2, which I wrote, yay!), try to simplify the implementation to make it easier to understand.

But in the end, its exactly the same algorithm:

1. Take the input, calculate the coordinates of the 4 corners of the square (for 2D Perlin noise, or cube if using the 3D version) containing the input point
2. Calculate a random value for all 4 of them (by first assigning a random gradient vector to each one (there are 4 possibilities in 2D: (+1, +1), (-1, +1), (-1, -1) and (+1, -1)), then calculating the dot product between this random gradient vector and the vector from the corner of the square to the input point)
3. Finally, smoothly interpolate between those 4 random values to get a final value

In article #1, the grad function returns the dot product directly, whereas in article #2, vector objects are created and a dot product function is called to make it explicit what is being done (this will probably be a bit slower than the other implementations since a lot of vector objects are created and used briefly each time you want to run the algorithm).

Whether 2 implementations will produce the same terrain / height maps depends on if they generate the same random values for each corner of the square/cube (the results of the dot products). If 2 algorithms generate the same random values for every single integer points on the grid (all the corners of all the possible squares/cubes), then they will produce the same results. Ken Perlin's original implementation and the 3 articles all use an array of integers to generate a random gradient vector for each corner (out of 4 possible choices) to calculate the dot product. So in theory if the arrays are identical, then they should produce the same results. (Unless maybe if some implementation uses another method to generate the random vectors.)

I'm not really sure if that answers you questions, so don't hesitate to ask something else :)

Edit:

Generally, you would not use Perlin noise alone. So for every final value you want (for example a single pixel in a height map texture), you would call the noise function multiple times (octaves). For example:

```
float finalValue = 0.0f;
float amplitude = 1.0f;
float frequency = 1.0f;
int octaveCount = 8;

for (int octave = 0; octave < octaveCount; ++octave) {
    finalValue += amplitude * noise(x * frequency, y * frequency, z * frequency);
    amplitude *= 0.5f;
    frequency *= 2.0f;
}

// Do something fun with 'finalValue'
```

Frequency, amplitude and the number of octaves are the most common parameters you can play with to produce different values.

If, say, you are generating a terrain, you would want many octaves. The first one will produce the rough shape of the mountains, so you would want a high amplitude (1.0 in the example code) and low frequency (also 1.0 in the above code). But just this octave would result in really smooth terrain with no details. For those small details, you would want more octaves, but with higher frequencies (so in the same range for your inputs (x, y, z), you would have a lot more ups and downs of the Perlin noise value), and lower amplitudes (you want small details, because if you would keep the same amplitude as the first octave (1.0, in the example code), there would be a lot of ups and downs really close together and really high, and this would result in a really rough moutains (imagine 100 meters 80 degrees drops and slopes every few meters you walk))

You can play with those parameters to get different results. There is also something called "domain warping" or "warped noise" that you can look up. Basically, you call a noise function as the input of a noise function. Like instead of calling:

```
float result = noise(x, y, z);
```

You would call something like:

```
// The numbers used are arbitrary values, you can just play around until you get something cool
float result = noise(noise(x * 1.7), 0.5 * noise(y * 4.1), noise(z * 2.3));
```

This can produce [really interesting results](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsl3RH)

Comment: Using multiple layers of noise is related to _fractal Brownian motion_ or _fractional Brownian motion_.